# Explicit null parameter

Tags: scala

I' new to scala and recently I came across the following piece of code:

```
object Foo {
    implicit lazy val myGlobalExecutionContext: ExecutionContextExecutor =
    impl.ExecutionContextImpl.fromExecutor(null: Executor)
}
```

I have checked the `fromExecutor` signature and it's like this

```
def fromExecutor(e: Executor): ExecutionContextExecutor
```

My question is why did we do :

```
impl.ExecutionContextImpl.fromExecutor(null: Executor)
```

and not simply

```
impl.ExecutionContextImpl.fromExecutor(null)
```

And why do we pass a type of the parameter when invoking a method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't see any particular reason in this case, but `fromExecutor` could be overloaded, and we might want to ensure a particular overload is called. For example:

```
case class Bar(id: Int)
case object Baz

object Test {
    def fromBar(bar: Bar): Bar = bar
    def fromBar(baz: Baz): Bar = Bar(0)
}
```

If I call:

```
scala> Test.fromBar(null)
<console>:20: error: ambiguous reference to overloaded definition,
both method fromBar in object Test of type (baz: Baz)Bar
and  method fromBar in object Test of type (bar: Bar)Bar
match argument types (Null)
              Test.fromBar(null)
```

I get an error because the call is ambiguous. `null` could be `Bar` or `Baz`. So I must use a type cast or ascription to use a specific overload:

```
 Test.fromBar(null: Bar)
```